# Selenium Webdriver throws timeout excption for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, automated-tests

I have updated version of chrome as well as WebDriver. Still getting the timeout exception. It was working properly previously but suddenly it started giving exception. It is not even reaching to test as well. If anyone has solution lease help.

`Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

`Webdriver: WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32 2.35.0`

```
var smth = m_driver.WaitUrl(new Regex(settings.GetSiteString("xyz") + "#/.*"));

for (int maxWait = 60000; maxWait > 0; maxWait--, System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500))
    if (m_driver.FindElement("//div[@ng-show='vm.loaded']").Displayed)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        return;
    }

throw new TimeoutException("Failed to wait for xyz page to load.");
```

Error message: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:63425/session/cdc3e59/url timed out after 120 seconds.

Comment: Please provide more information, like the script you try to run. The exact versions you're using etc.

Comment: chrome version - Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)
WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32 2.35.0

Comment: Selenium Versions? Script?

Comment: What it mean by script? Where I will get that? Sorry I am new to these tests

Comment: The Test-Script you try to execute?

Comment: m_driver.WaitUrl(new Regex(settings.GetSiteString("xyz") + "#/.*"));

            for (int maxWait = 60000; maxWait > 0; maxWait--, System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500))
                if (m_driver.FindElement("//div[@ng-show='vm.loaded']").Displayed)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    return;
                }

            throw new TimeoutException("Failed to wait for xyz page to load.");

Comment: Please update your Question with this informations. Also please add the exact error message you receive.

Comment: @Shraddha , which version of selenium are you using?

Comment: Selenium Version - 1.0.19.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding the `no-sandbox` argument to your chrome driver options fixes the problem. I'm still trying to figure out why this fixes it.

Here is an example of how to instantiate a ChromeDriver so that it doesn't give you timeouts on pages that actually load properly.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

var webDriver = new ChromeDriver(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), chromeOptions);
```

I found this solution in [this Github thread](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5457)